# Finding the shortest subarray that contains k 1's in a binary array

Tags: python, algorithm

Consider that we have an array of 1's and 0's ( a binary array).
We want to find an algorithm that finds the shortest subarray that contains k 1's.
Just to make it clear, the subarray can contain any amount of 0's but it must contain k 1's.
The algorithm must have time complexiy of O(n).

I tried to write a python code for this problem and this is what I've done so far:

```
def subarray(arr, k):
    sp = 0  # The starting point of the subarray
    ep = 0   #The ending point of the subarray
    count = 0
    result = (0, 0)
    n = len(arr)
    # Finding a sp
    for i in range(0, n):
        if arr[i]==1:
            sp = i
            count+=1
            break
    #finding a ep
    for i in range(sp+1, n):
        if arr[i]==1:
            count+=1
        if count==k:
            ep = i
            result = (sp, ep)
            break
    sp+=1
    ep+=1
    sfound = False
    efound = False
    while(1):
        if ep>n:
            break
        if arr[sp]==1:
            sfound = True
        elif(sfound==False and arr[sp]!=1):
            sp+=1
        if arr[ep]==1:
            efound = True
        elif(efound==False and arr[ep]!=1):
            ep+=1
        if (ep-sp)<(result[1]-result[0]):
            resut = (sp, ep)
        # reseting every thing to start again
        sp+=1
        ep+=1
        sfound = False
        efound = False
    return result

#main()
A=[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
k = 7
print(subarray(A,k))
```

But I think I wrote it in a complicated way, and it's doesn't give the right answer. I don't khow what's my mistake is?!

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Answer (score 4):

Use two pointers, and keep track of the count of ones between them. Advance the appropriate counter to get & maintain k ones. Keep track of the min distance between pointers where you have k ones.